# New collators not peering - shouldHavePeers: false

Tags: networking, collator

In our parachain setup we have one healthy collator node producing blocks.
I tried to add two bootnodes and one collator to the set (all of them connecting to the existing collator). So for the bootnodes and the other collator, all of them were specifying the first healthy collator as "bootnode".

All the nodes discover each other, so they show 3 peers and, calling the RPC method `system.peers()` on each of them shows that they are the correct ones.

The problem comes when nor the new collator (which is part of the invulnerable set) or the other two nodes, show activity in the network as the existing collator does (i.e. they are stuck in an old block). So it appears to me to be like a stalled subset of nodes.
Inspecting the RPC `system.health()` on the healthy node shows:

```
{
  peers: 3
  isSyncing: false
  shouldHavePeers: false
}
```

So that calls my attention: `shouldHavePeers` is `false`, while in the other 3 nodes is `true`. Does anyone know what exactly **shouldHavePeers** means, why is it `false`, and how to make the node axtually accept the other peers ?
Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I know from [here](https://crates.parity.io/sc_rpc/system/struct.Health.html#structfield.should_have_peerssystem.chainType) that `should_have_peers` "Might be false for local chains or when running without discovery". This doesn't help too much, since it is not a Local network and we are not specifically running without discovery.

EDIT 2:
`system.chainType` is `Live` for all the nodes.

Comment: Could you share the result of the rpc query `system.chainType` ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting, the chain type is Live (I've updated my post). Anyway We managed to make them peer but we are not really sure how. I will try to elaborate an answer to close the question.

Comment: Any news about how you find the solution?